# AFrame scene reload method

Tags: aframe

i'm trying to reload the scene on AFrame, i have a scene with a robot and i need to load back to original state of the scene when users click a button.

What i already tried is:

```
var sceneElement = document.querySelector("a-scene");
  sceneElement.reload();
```

And:

```
location.reload()
```

The first one raise an error on browser console showing that `reload()` method is not a function but documentation on [AFrame](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/core/scene.html#methods_reload) supports it. I don't know if i'm using this function right.

```
Uncaught TypeError: sceneElement.reload is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (websim.js:64)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (editor.js:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4953)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4758)
```

The last code from below reloads the entire page and this is not what i need.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method was removed a while ago, I just pushed a change to remove that from the docs, thanks.

You can do `window.location.reload()`.

Else you can just revert whatever you need reverted manually (`.setAttribute`s, removing components). `aframe-state-component` can also help if it's more complex and you don't want a page reload.

Comment: Can i set back rotation and position for the robot in my scene with `aframe-state-component`?

Comment: If you want to go that route, I'd define an initial state variable that contains everything you want reset. `var initialState = {robotPosition: '0 0 0'};` and then `AFRAME.registerState({initialState: initialState, handlers: { reset: function (state) { Object.assign(state, initialState); } } })`....Then bind the state `<a-entity robot bind__position="robotPosition" then just emit `reset` to scene. You can also have a robot component that does it for you with an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my problem, my robot has `dynamic-body` component so i'm able to use `robot.body.quaternion.set` with robot.body.initQuaternion x, y and z as input parameters and reload the robot.

I know is not the full scene reloaded but it works fine for this particular issue.

Thank you @ngokevin for your answers